# What am I? A rhyming riddle

Tags: riddle, word

This is a simple riddle I thought up a while ago:

---

I'm tossed by the wind that blows about,

I trip on hills and mountains too,

I like to cry and weep and pout,

But when I'm angry, watch please do,

I take my hammer, beat my drum,

And all the world hears me pound,

My melody is rough and deep,

My angry tears are running down,

With my arms, I take down trees,

I slap water, house and flag,

All with limbs that snake and writhe,

(Please do not mind, I like to brag.)

I do this all with darkened face,

But when I'm  happy, you behold,

My face is light and pure and glad!

I'm always happy! Never sad!

And though through dusk, we come to nigh,

I still walk gently up on high,

And now I ask you, will you try,

To find my riddle: What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be:

> Clouds

I'm tossed by the wind that blows about,

> Clouds are moved by the wind

I trip on hills and mountains too,

> Clouds can interact with hills and mountains

I like to cry and weep and pout,

> Rain

But when I'm angry, watch please do,
I take my hammer, beat my drum,

> Thunder clouds

And all the world hears me pound,
My melody is rough and deep,
My angry tears are running down,

> Thunder storm

With my arms, I take down trees,
I slap water, house and flag,
All with limbs that snake and writhe,
(Please do not mind, I like to brag.)

> Thunder clouds, or maybe even hurricane

I do this all with darkened face,

> Thunder clouds are dark

But when I'm happy, you behold,
My face is light and pure and glad!
I'm always happy! Never sad!

> Regular clouds are generally depicted as happy and bright

And though through dusk, we come to nigh,
I still walk gently up on high,

> Even at night, clouds still in the sky

And now I ask you, will you try,
To find my riddle: What am I?

> Clouds, I hope!

Comment: For riddles set in this type, it is considered more polite and standard to provide an explanation of each line, or at least combination of lines, in the riddle.

Comment: You're correct except for the "With my arms, I take down trees, I slap water, house and flag, All with limbs that snake and writhe" part. That was lightning.